# average of distinct date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column that contains dates, and some dates are repeated. Each time it's repeated, it means it's a new request. I want to display the average number of requests per date. I want to know how many requests we receive per day on average. How can I achieve this, please?

```
NombreDemandesPourDate = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('demande'),
    FILTER(
        'demande',
        'demande'[date_insert] = 'demande'[date_insert]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as a **Measure**:

```
NombreDemandesPourDate = 
  AVERAGEX(
    DISTINCT('demande'[date_insert]),
    CALCUALTE(COUNTROWS('demande'))
  )
```

Comment: it has to count for each date_insert the number of occurence then devise it on the sum of distinct date insert, how can i do that please ?

Comment: That is what the above does. For each unique date, count the number it occurs, then average.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the total number of rows in your demande table (effectively counting every request).
Then count the number of distinct dates in your date_insert column.
Now you have everything to divide the total number of requests by the total number of distinct dates to get the average number of requests per date.

```
AverageRequestsPerDate =
VAR TotalRequests = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('demande'))
VAR TotalDistinctDates = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('demande'[date_insert]))
RETURN DIVIDE(TotalRequests, TotalDistinctDates)
```